# How to migate from IMAP to Exchange

Tags: email, exchange, migration, imap, hosted-exchange

I have about 30 accounts that I have to migrate from IMAP based folder system to an exchange based system. Th desktops all run OSX apple mail.

I have access to all the credentials for all the accounts. There is currently mail being delivered to both sets of accounts. (not my fault, the hosted exchange accounts recongise the domain and deliver locally instead of to the main mail server).

In effect what I would like to do is run a script/app/program that checks account A and if the email is not in account B, move it over.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I should add that I don't have access to the exchange backend

Comment: I have edited my answer to address that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily enable IMAP on the Exchange server and use a program like [imapcopy](http://home.arcor.de/armin.diehl/imapcopy/imapcopy.html) or [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) to transfer each account's email.

There is a list of software that can do this for you on the imapsync web site.

Since you do not have access to the Exchange Server configuration, you can use [Microsoft Transporter Suite](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=1329).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImapSync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) to run this at the server-to-server level. If you don't have access to the Exchange server setup (e.g. its IMAP settings), you could simply add the Exchange account to the users' Apple Mail clients so that both accounts are displayed simultaneously. From there, copy the mail/folders from the IMAP account to the newly-created Exchange account.